# Why is While not showing any output?

Tags: finite-fields

I'm trying to use the Finite Fields package to show that $x$ is not a primitive element of $\mathbb{Z}_3[x]/\langle x^3 + 2x + 2 \rangle \cong GF(3^3)$. The idea is to take the following piece of code:

```
i = 1;
While[ReduceElement[GF[3, {2, 2, 0, 1}][{0, 1, 0}]^i] != 
      ReduceElement[GF[3, {2, 2, 0, 1}][{1}]], Print[i]; i++]
```

which should compute all the powers of $x$ and terminate when it reaches the identity. However, it does not produce any output; I even inserted the Print statement to make sure it would at least do *something*, but I still get nada. What is going on here? How can I make this piece of code work the way it's supposed to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the condition you wrote does not evaluate to `True`. For e.g. with `i=12` it gives

```
ReduceElement[GF[3, {2, 2, 0, 1}][{0, 1, 0}]^12] != ReduceElement[GF[3, {2, 2, 0, 1}][{1}]]
  (*Subscript[{2, 0, 1}, 3] != Subscript[{1, 0, 0}, 3]*)
```

But it does evaluate to `False` for `i=13`

```
ReduceElement[GF[3, {2, 2, 0, 1}][{0, 1, 0}]^13] != ReduceElement[GF[3, {2, 2, 0, 1}][{1}]]
 (*False*)
```

So the solution is to write the condition such that it evaluates to `True` and `False`. The code below works and it prints till the `False` condition is found.

```
 i = 1;
 While[Not[
 ReduceElement[GF[3, {2, 2, 0, 1}][{0, 1, 0}]^i] === 
 ReduceElement[GF[3, {2, 2, 0, 1}][{1}]]], Print[i]; i++]
```

Comment: you could use `=!=` as well..

Comment: Thanks. Can you explain what the difference is between the two conditions such that one evaluates to true but the other does not?

Comment: see documentation for [Unequal](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Unequal.html). **Returns True if elements are guaranteed unequal, and otherwise stays unevaluated**.

Comment: This deserves a little more explanation, the object `Subscript[{2, 0, 1}, 3]` is effectively a symbol that can be assigned a value.  Since yours presumably do not have values, they may or may not be equal. (Same as `x==y` will return unevaluated if `x` and `y` do not have values)